# How to make the LoCoH toolbox work in ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I'm trying to estimate home range with the Local Convex  method. I cannot make the LoCoH toolbox work in ArcMap 10.2. I get following error:

Executing: alocoh "C:\Users\Linn\Desktop\Fra Bjørn\Export_Output.shp" 1 3 1 100 # #
Start Time: Mon Nov 10 13:56:12 2014
Running script alocoh...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\locoh.py", line 14, in 
    R.Init('R')
  File "", line 2, in Init
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Undtagelse opstod.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147221485), None)

Failed to execute (alocoh).
Failed at Mon Nov 10 13:56:12 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0,12 seconds)

Could it just be that my version of ArcGIS is to new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but the last version appears to be for 9.x. The object calls in ArcGIS >=10 have completely changed and it is doubtful that you will be able to get the toolbox to work.

In addition the R ade package has been completely overhauled and is no longer compatible with the underlying toolbox Python code. The entire toolbox and associated R code would have to be rewritten.

The current R package containing LoCoH is adehabitatHR. [Here is the current package help for the Getz et al., (2007) LoCoH function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/adehabitatHR/docs/LoCoH). In addition to LoCoH, there are also several other Kernel volume estimates available in adehabitatHR. The ade packages are now sp compliant making it easy to read in and  utilize spatial data with results being in a object class that is easy to read back out as GIS formats.